# This Stream Does Not Support Seek Operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, stream, io

This is a follow-up to: [Getting Started With ASP.NET MVC3 & Google Checkout: Take 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295359/getting-started-with-asp-net-mvc3-google-checkout-take-2)

It seems that the problem why I'm getting a Bad Request (400 error) - refer to the topic above - is because of this error. Checkout the screen shot below:

[image]

So as you can see, there's an exception being thrown and that's probably what's causing all the mess. I tried using a `MemoryStream` but I got an exception telling me that it cannot cast a `System.Net.ConnectStream` to a `MemoryStream`. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a false lead. Ignore that. You are only seeing that because of the debugger / visualiser trying to show you all the properties (some of which don't make sense for a stream of unknown length).

That said, I'm not sure how it makes sense to add that stream to view-data. Streams are *pipes*, not *buckets*. With a few exceptions they don't actually hold the data - they are just intermediaries to a data source / sink.

In terms of finding an actual problem, you need to `catch` the actual exception that is happening in the code. Ignore anything you see in the visualiser; that is not what your code uses.

I *suspect* this "connect" stream (I'm not familiar) is intended to be used as a sink - meaning: you write to it. However, to serialize (for view-data) it might be trying to *read* it. This is just supposition, however, unless you indicate the actual exception that your code is raising (ignoring the visualiser).

Comment: I do not really want to add it to the ViewData, it's just a way I used to inspect the stream. What I want to do eventually is get the damn call to Google Checkout working correctly. The exception I'm getting (the real one) is a 400 error: Bad Request. Since there isn't anything I could think of that might be causing the problem, I thought I'd inspect all the objects in play to see if there's anything fishy about them and I found out about that stream issue.

Comment: @Kassem are you getting the 400 from google? Or are your server raising the 400? If it is the first, I suggest your data (request to google) is wrong.

Comment: I do not think it's my server raising the 400. It's definitely Google's server. The call is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295359/getting-started-with-asp-net-mvc3-google-checkout-take-2

Comment: @Kassem as noted on the previous question, you are going to have to use a tool like fiddler to see what you are sending. It sounds like you are simply sending the wrong stuff. This visualiser issue is unrelated.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the results I got in Fiddler confirm the visual issue or not (I do not think so, because I saw the data being sent). But take a look at it please, maybe you can see something I couldn't see... Thank you :)